# Language recognizers in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, grammar

I wanted to know if there are any language recognizers/parsers in sql (we use Oracle as our relational database) similar to third party libraries like antlr or javacc in java. The intent is to define a grammar which can parse a language(string) and convert it to a sql query.

Comment: Why do you think the parser needs to reside within Oracle as opposed to an external program?

Comment: Since the parser transforms the user defined string into a SQL query, I thought it would best to have the query creation code in the database where it's suppose to executed. This would avoid modifications in the java code when SQL query optimizations (for performance) are to be applied. Do you think that it would be the right way to design such an application?

Answer (score 2):

Not built-in, but in Oracle you can write stored procedures in Java and have access to antlr, cup, javacc, jflex, etc.

Comment: Ok. If they are not built-in then it would be better to do them in java compared to doing it in java stored procedures since it would not be much of an help.

Comment: I agree that there wouldn't be much benefit to having the parser as a stored procedure.